# WordPress Error establishing a database connection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am new to WordPress, and I am trying to setup it at my local machine.

I am getting error like "Error establishing a database connection".

I tried all solutions from WP blogs,

- 1. created new user with all privileges
- 2. tired with root user.
- 3. created and deleted the target database multiple times.

Nothing is working.

Does anyone know anything else I can try?

Comment: How do you have your local db set up?

Comment: Thanks for comment,Actually i was wrongly configured the wp-config.php file,after fixing  all worked well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Error establishing a database connection` doesn't get any simpler than that. Your password, database name, user name, or host is wrong. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors#Error_Establishing_Database_Connection

Are you sure about using `localhost` as the server? Are you using MAMP or WAMP?

Try using Adminer http://www.adminer.org/ on your PC/Mac to find the database name, etc., and to admin the database when needed.

If you know can use a shell, try logging into the MySQL server and trying

`mysql> show databases;`

to list all databases to check your database name.

And try

`mysql> mysqlserverinfo --server=root:pass@localhost -d --format=vertical`

to get port info, etc. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/mysqlserverinfo.html

Comment: @marlrateldge thanks, the problem is fixed there is problem in database details, i was passing wrong details

Comment: This can also occur if there is corrupted data in tables. It's possibly more complicated than invalid credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I used MAMP for the MySQL server, and used its phpMyAdmin interface to create the database for WordPress and specify its user and password.

Host, for the new database, was "%" on the "User" tab of phpMyAdmin, which it said was supposed to allow any value, and did let me get a certain way through the process.  But, I ended up going into "Login Information" under the "User" tab in phpMyAdmin, and changing "%" to "localhost".

That allowed me to finish setting up WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, if you are on OSX Yosemite (possibly other versions of OSX as well) and get "Error establishing a database connection" with a local WordPress installation, you may need to do the following:

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo chmod 755 /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Yosemite looks in the wrong location for the mysql.sock file, so creating this symlink to the correct location solves the problem.

The reason the missing symlink is a problem for WordPress specifically is because in your wp-config.php file, `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');` will not work. An alternative workaround is to change this value in your wp-config file to `define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');`.

The OP didn't say what details they changed in their wp-config file to solve the problem (perhaps it was this DB_HOST parameter) so I just thought I'd post this since I wasted a lot of time trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

I tried all these suggestions and still couldn't get it to work. However, I had installed MySQL v8.0.12 and noticed that in the 'Users and Privileges' section, under the user I had set up, the 'Authentication Type' for the password was set to some kind of 'sha2' setting.

After trying 100 different things, I eventually fixed this by uninstalling then re-installing MySQL, and during the re-installation, specifically choosing the option button that refers to maintaining compatibility with previous versions of MySQL.

I think this resulted in my passwords not being automatically hashed, which enabled Wordpress to successfully connect to my MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: 
-I moved the wp-config.php file into another folder 
-Refreshed the browser and Wordpress will try to re-install 
 
-choose a language  
-A message should say Wordpress is already installed and will take you to the database setup page. 
-Enter the same db name, username, password, and host (usually localhost). 
-Got to www.yoursite.com/admin and you should be able to log in.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I have searched a lot but no one mentioned a fix like mine!
I checked my disk size and I found that my disk size was 100% used. I tried to clean up some of the files but still there were very large files taking up a lot of space. I kept looking and found that the mysql ./data folder occupied 90% of my disk space. It was the binlog files! Very large files I ended up cleaning them up using the [Reset Master](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reset-master.html) method. There is another method [PURGE BINARY LOGS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/purge-binary-logs.html) which didn't work for me. I had to use Reset Master. Just follow the steps and make sure you have a good backup. Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

Try this before anything! It fixed my issue.

`sudo service mysql restart`