# "Localhost Error establishing a database connection "

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am new to WordPress, and I am trying to setup it at my local machine.

I am getting error like "Error establishing a database connection".please help me to solve this error..

Comment: is the database Server started?

Comment: You should describe what are you doing step-by-step so that the issue is reproducible. It is unlikely that you get help otherwise. Please also consider asking at wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress Error establishing a database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516102/wordpress-error-establishing-a-database-connection)

Answer (score 1):

Without your database code, it is hard to figure the exact reason.

The error is usually due to:

**Your MySQL server is not running. So you need to run this command if you are on a Linux machine (May not work for Ubuntu):**

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

Or,

- The MySQL user does not have the privileges to access the Wordpress
  database
- The port 3306 is blocked. Check what other program is using that
  port.
- The host name in Wordpress configuration is not correct. Make sure it
  is 'localhost'

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly the proper way to address the problem, it's invaluable to learn how to navigate and work with the wp-config file, Apache, and MySQL - but this should solve your problem, and is very friendly for someone just getting started with this sort of thing.

The correct fix (in my opinion) is to set up a WAMP server, or at least Apache, MySQL, and PHP to run Wordpress locally.

You probably are looking for something more like: http://www.instantwp.com/

I have used it before.  Basically, you install and it creates a virtual temporary server where you can develop without needing to mess with the details of Apache, wp-config, or SQL.  Very easy, hope that helps.  Cheers.